# Global servlet exception handling in OSGI. How?

Tags: java, exception, servlets, osgi, karaf

Is there a way to somehow globally handle unchecked exceptions in osgi (karaf) that were thrown in servlets?

What I mean is something like in `Spring`, where there is `@ControllerAdvice` where you can specify methods for each exception type and handle it.

I would like to unify the exception handling in my rest api that exposes osgi services.

Answer (score 1):

### Doing REST in OSGi

You mention REST and Servlets in this question. If you're using REST in OSGi then the JAX-RS Whiteboard is the easiest way to do things. If you want to use raw Servlets, then the Http Whiteboard is the way to go. Both models make it easy to handle exceptions.

#### Update

In an effort to make it easier for people to see how this works, I've created a working example [on GitHub](https://github.com/timothyjward/web-error-handling) which covers Servlets and JAX-RS error handling.

### Using the HTTP Whiteboard

The HTTP whiteboard allows servlets to be registered as OSGi services and then used to handle requests. One type of request handling is to act as an *error page*.

Error pages are registered with the `osgi.http.whiteboard.servlet.errorPage` property. The value of this property is one or more Strings containing either:

- A fully qualified class name for an exception that should be handled
- A three digit error code

The OSGi specification [describes this in an example](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.http.whiteboard.html#d0e120971), and other pages [list the attributes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-exception-handling.htm) that you can use to work out what went wrong.

For example this servlet will be called for `IOException`, `NullPointerException` and for status codes `401` and `403`:

```
@Component
@HttpWhiteboardServletErrorPage(errorPage = {"java.io.IOException", "java.lang.NullPointerException", "401", "403"})
public class MyErrorServlet extends HttpServlet implements Servlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws Exception {

        Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request
                .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");

        // Do stuff with the error
    }

}
```

N.B. I have used OSGi R7 Component Property Type annotations to make this simpler to read. It will work with older versions of DS and the Http Whiteboard equally well.

### Using the JAX-RS whiteboard

The JAX-RS Whiteboard [allows you to use any of the JAX-RS extension types as a whiteboard service](https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.jaxrs.html#service.jaxrs.extension.services). In this case you want an `ExceptionMapper`.

In this example we add a handler for `IOException`

```
@Component
@JaxrsExtension
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<IOException> {
    Response toResponse(IOException e) {
        // Create a response
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the advice. I have tried the approach involving `@HttpWhiteboardServletErrorPage` but it doesn't seem to work. My dependencies are: org.osgi.service.component.annotations 1.3.0, org.osgi.annotation 6.0.0, org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations 1.3.0, org.osgi.core 4.3.0, org.osgi.compendium 4.2.0, org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard 1.1.0, org.apache.felix.configadmin 1.8.16. I throw an exception in one of my servlets but it is not redirected to my new servlet marked with errorPage annotation.

Comment: As I mentioned in the response, the examples are using OSGi R7 (to make them easier to read). This also requires your build tools to be using bnd 4.1.0 (the first version with support for DS 1.4). If you want to use DS 1.3 (from OSGi R6) then you are probably better off adding the service properties the old-fashioned way (using the property element of the component annotation).

Comment: I've created an example repository on GitHub so that you can see this working. https://github.com/timothyjward/web-error-handling